# XSLT local number formatting

Tags: xslt-1.0

I tried with the xslt format-number to format the local numbers. I couldn't able to get this output.

```
1
10
100
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
10,00,000
1,00,00,000
10,00,00,000
```

using XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:variable name="t">123590</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($t, '##,##,##0')"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for the help.
Umesh

Comment: When I put this into http://fiddle.frameless.io/ it works fine and outputs `1,23,590` - so your problems seems to be related to a specific XSLT processor.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38643507/3016153

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT format-number with comma for indian price](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641504/xslt-format-number-with-comma-for-indian-price)

Answer (score 0):

*Copied from: [XSLT format-number with comma for indian price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641504/xslt-format-number-with-comma-for-indian-price/38643507#38643507)*

---

Float and integer INR Number formats in XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:variable name="Value">301050101</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">

        <!-- 1
10
100
1,000
10,000
1,00,000
10,00,000
1,00,00,000
10,00,00,000 -->

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($Value,'.')">
            <xsl:variable name="integerValue" select="substring-before($Value,'.')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="floatValue" select="substring-after($Value,'.')"/>
            <!--                <xsl:value-of select="$integerValue"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$floatValue"/> -->
            <xsl:call-template name="INR_Number_Format">
                <xsl:with-param name="integerValue" select="$integerValue"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$floatValue"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="INR_Number_Format">
                <xsl:with-param name="integerValue" select="$Value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="INR_Number_Format">
    <xsl:param name="integerValue"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$integerValue >= 1000">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($integerValue div 1000), '#,##')" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($integerValue mod 1000, '000')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($integerValue, '#,###')" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope it helps :) .