# decimal format in XSLT along with characters

Tags: xslt

I'm completely new to XSL and I have a query on how to convert a number into decimal format when we have text in the XML node.

For example:

```
<Salary> 15000 USD </Salary>
```

Expected out:

15,000 USD

I've used the below transformation (which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38643507/3016153)), however it only converts when there is no text:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$Salary >= 1000">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($Salary div 1000), '#,##')" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($Salary mod 1000, '000')" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($Salary, '#,###')" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your example value is not numeric so the comparison will probably be comparing strings.  You will need to remove alpha characters and then compare.  Or separate your field into the number and currency components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you need to convert the input to a number by removing all non-digit characters.

Assuming you are using XSLT 1.0, that would be done as:

```
<xsl:variable name="salary" select="translate(Salary, translate(Salary, '0123456789', ''), '')"/>
```

*Here we assume the input will be always a positive integer - hence no minus sign or decimal point.*

Once you have that, you can proceed to format the resulting number as:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$salary  >= 1000">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($salary div 1000), '#,##')" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($salary mod 1000, '000')" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($salary, '#,###')" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:text> USD</xsl:text>
```

---

**Note:**

It looks like you want to format the number as Indian currency - which seems very strange, given that the amount is in USD.

Comment: I will need the text USD to also appear in the result, I have no control over the XML (it comes from another source, so no changes can made to that).

Comment: @Venkat The text " USD" does appear in the result. No changes to the XML are necessary - the stylesheet does all the work. See a demo here: http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHZ

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael, much appreciated. This has really helped to finish my task. I'm already reading w3schools to get a hang of XSLT Do you suggest any other resources?